# Show Loader when submitting form In laravel collective

Tags: laravel, laravel-form

I am submitting a form directly without using Ajax request, I want to show loader when getting a response from the backend.
How is it possible?

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['patient_signup'], 'method' => 'post', 'name' => 'sign_up_form']) !!}
```

and in controller

```
public function patient_signup()
{
    if ($result) {
        return redirect(route('home'))->with('success', $message);
    } else {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('error', $message);
    }
}
```

Everything working fine but I want to show loader when getting a response from the backend.
Please provide me a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can add div tag after body tag like below

```
<body>
<div  class="pageLoader" id="pageLoader"></div>
```

In css

```
.pageLoader{
    background: url(../images/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999999;
    background-color: #ffffff8c;

}
```

then in JavaScript

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    
        $('#pageLoader').show();
    
    });
    
    $(function () {
    
        $('#pageLoader').hide();
    })
```

**Updated**

```
 return redirect(route('home'))->with('success', $message)->with('loader',true);
```

then in JavaScript

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
          @if(isset($loader))
            $('#pageLoader').show();
@endif
        
        });
        
        $(function () {
        
            $('#pageLoader').hide();
        })
```

Comment: yes if you still need on on submssion then you might pass query param like ?loader=true then you need to handle it in jquery

Comment: this one works but not works according to what I want.Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you're fudging this a little. Spinners typically work with `ajax` requests as the spinner provides a visual feedback that an action is ongoing. The action being a `request` has been sent to the server by the browser and the browser is now waiting on a `response`. The `response` is required in order to remove the spinner (`response` could also be a failure or timeout etc.) and the spinner is removed without a page refresh.

In your use case, the `response` from the server is in fact redirecting the user to another page, or back to the form page with errors.

So basically what you want to do is have a `loading` indicator (spinner, words, etc.) which is initially `hidden` and you display when the form is submitted and it will automatically disappear if the user is redirected back to your form page.

As an example:

```html
<div class="relative grid place-items-center h-screen">
  <form id="some-form">

    <button id="form-submit" class="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 rounded text-white">Submit</button>

  </form>
  <div id="loader" class="hidden" style="display: none">
    Loading ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Then your javascript:

```js
let form = document.querySelector('#some-form');
let loader = document.querySelector('#loader')

form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    // using non css framework method with Style
    loader.style.display = 'block';
  
    // using a css framework such as TailwindCSS
    loader.classList.remove('hidden');

    // pretend the form has been sumitted and returned
    setTimeout(() => loader.style.display = 'none', 1000);
});
```

You could use `jQuery` or whatever you want but you get the idea. Example [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/noe2trLc/1/).

Comment: want to display Spinners because when submitting the form it will sending 3 mail to users in the back side so it takes time.

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya That's fine, no judgement from me. Your reasoning for using something is down to you. My solution is a basic example of the workflow, the specific implementation (use of a spinner graphic, styling etc.) is down to you.